# How to use a custom git command in vscode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, latex, overleaf

Is there a way to customize vscodes git commands? Ideally I'd like to be able to use something like:

```
git push overleaf main:master
```

and

```
git pull overleaf master:main
```

using vscode -- as well as have the automatic fetching.

I haven't been able to figure it out by looking at the settings. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't answer anything about vscode itself, but `git pull overleaf master:main` is not something you should do with command-line Git. When using different branch names in the local repository and various remote repositories, things get tricky: the push syntax you're using is correct, but since pull isn't the opposite of push in the first place, the pull syntax you're using ... well, it's not *wrong*, it just means something you probably shouldn't be doing.

Comment: I completely agree! However this is a specific case where this is the only thing I've gotten to work so I just wanted to see If it was possible to do this using vscode